# How to return all records using IN clause when parameter is empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm passing a parameter like '1,2,3' to this statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Negative
WHERE IdNegative IN (@IdNegative)
```

But I want to return all records (like the records with an id 1,2,3,4,5,6...) when the parameter is empty. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: `'1,2,3'` and the **three** `integer` values `1`, `2`, and `3` are completely different things. Use a table type parameter.

Comment: The statement itself is already wrong. You must pass multiple values, not one value that is CSV. Example: `SELECT * FROM Negative WHERE IdNegative IN (@IdNegative1, @IdNegative2, @IdNegative3)`

Comment: Presumably `@IdNegative` is a table-type parameter?

Comment: @Stu - based on the first line in the question I doubt it.

Comment: It *can't* be [a table-type parameter] with syntax like `IN (@IdNegative)`. If it *is* the above would very likely error as the scalar variable `@IdNegative` hasn't been declared.

Comment: `WHERE @IdNegative IS NULL OR IdNegative IN (@IdNegative)`

Comment: Is this perhaps SSRS?

Comment: @juergend If `@IdNegative` is a table type parameter that will be invalid syntax.  If it's a scalar then work needs to be done to unpack the string in order to get the list out to be able to check.

Comment: A good idea, @DaleK, but if it is, then the above should be working (though I *hate* that SSRS accepts syntax like `IN (@IdNegative)` and injects the parameters, it teaches people bad syntax),

Comment: Ok, right. So I think it doesn't work the way I need. Thank you guys for the clarifications.

Comment: @DaleK I'm using in JasperReports, but I need to find another way.

Comment: Hi, is this SSRS? if not, sounded like you require a custom table type to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Parameters and variables are not simply pasted into the query by the compiler. They are inserted as actual compiled values, so in this case the string `1,2,3` is never going to be equal to any of the numbers `1` `2` `3`.

You need to declare as a table variable or as a Table-Valued Parameter

```sql
DECLARE @IdNegative TABLE (id int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @IdNegative VALUES (1),(2),(3);

SELECT *
FROM Negative
WHERE IdNegative IN (SELECT id FROM @IdNegative);
```

Comment: Or parse the string and fill a table within the batch, or use dynamic sql to inject the string into a statement.

Comment: No don't do any of those. Do it properly, with set-based tables. Anything else (such as `OPENJSON` or `LIKE` or dynamic SQL) is simply a hack

Comment: I don't disagree, but if the appropriate changes can't be made then you have to resort to what's possible.